# Is there a way to get the uv coords of the cursor in a mouse event on an object?

Tags: aframe

I’m trying to spawn an element on an object at the location that the cursor intersects it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cursor implementation that comes with A-Frame (designed for Cardboard experiences) wraps the raycaster component.

The raycaster does all the intersection work. The cursor component adds additional events.

**On master branch / 0.3.0**, when listening to cursor events, the event detail will contain full intersection data.

```
el.addEventListener('click', function (evt) { console.log(evt.detail.intersection); });
```

https://aframe.io/docs/master/components/cursor.html
https://aframe.io/docs/master/components/raycaster.html